# How to prove this inequality of bounded complex number.?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

$|a_1\cdots a_m - b_1\cdots b_m|\leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^m|a_i-b_i|$

Where $|a_i|\leq 1, |b_i|\leq 1$, and they are any complex number satisfying the condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove the following inequality $|\prod_{i=1}^{i=n}a_i-\prod_{i=1}^{i=n}b_i| < n\delta$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343282/how-to-prove-the-following-inequality-prod-i-1i-na-i-prod-i-1i-nb)

Comment: Or this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2560702/42969.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's prove the result for $m=2$. Aplying the triangle inequality:-

$$|a_1a_2 - b_1b_2|=|a_1(a_2-b_2)+b_2(a_1-b_1)|\le |a_1 - b_1|+|a_2 - b_2|.$$

Then $|a_1\cdots a_m - b_1\cdots b_m|$ can be written as $|(a_1\cdots a_{m-1})a_m - (b_1\cdots b_{m-1})b_m|$.

Applying the result for $m=2$ gives an upper bound of $$|(a_1\cdots a_{m-1}) - (b_1\cdots b_{m-1})|+|a_m - b_m|$$ and repeated application of this result gives the required inequality.

Comment: Thanks, I use it in proving the convergence of characteristic function

Answer (score 0):

By induction on $m$.

For $m = 2$ we have:

$$\begin{aligned}
\vert a_1 a_2 - b_1 b_2 \vert &= \vert a_1 a_2 -a_2 b_1 + a_2b_1 -b_1b_2 \vert\\
&\le \vert a_2 \vert \vert a_1 - b_1 \vert+ \vert b_1 \vert \vert a_2 - b_2 \vert\\
&\le \vert a_1 - b_1 \vert + \vert a_2 - b_2 \vert
\end{aligned}$$

Induction step from $m$ to $m+1$ follows from the case $m=2$, substituting in previous proof $a_1 \dots a_m \to a_1$, $b_1 \dots b_m \to b_1$, $a_{m+1} \to a_2$ and $b_{m+1} \to b_2$.